# How should I modify my query

Tags: mysql

I identified the most popular actor (topActor) within category using the following query:

```
SELECT category_id AS cid,
     (SELECT actor_id FROM 
 film_actor JOIN film_category 
   ON  film_actor.film_id = film_category.film_id
         WHERE category_id = cid 
         GROUP BY actor_id
         ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
         LIMIT 0,1) AS topActor
 FROM film_actor JOIN film_category 
   ON  film_actor.film_id = film_category.film_id
 GROUP BY category_id


+-----+----------+
| cid | topActor |
+-----+----------+
|   1 |       50 |
|   2 |      150 |
|   3 |       17 |
|   4 |       86 |
|   5 |      196 |
|   6 |       48 |
|   7 |        7 |
|   8 |       79 |
|   9 |      164 |
|  10 |       68 |
|  11 |       27 |
|  12 |      108 |
|  13 |      105 |
|  14 |      107 |
|  15 |       83 |
|  16 |       44 |
+-----+----------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I need to get the corresponding actor's ***first_name*** and ***last_name*** from the table ***actor***, containing actor_id, ***first_name*** and ***last_name*** . I know how to do it using PL/SQL or SAS, but I am new to MySQL. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using a nested query in `SELECT` clause - join it

Comment: Please post a sql filddle or atleast your relevant db structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far i understand you want to get the value of fname and lname from actor's table and the foreign key is actor_id so i think this will do.

```
SELECT category_id AS cid,
 (SELECT actor_id FROM 
 film_actor JOIN film_category 
 ON  film_actor.film_id = film_category.film_id
     WHERE category_id = cid 
     GROUP BY actor_id
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
     LIMIT 0,1) AS topActor, actor.fname, actor.lname
 FROM film_actor inner JOIN film_category 
 ON  film_actor.film_id = film_category.film_id inner join actor on film_actor.actor_id = actor.id
 GROUP BY category_id
```

I don't really understand what's your problem, so if this answer is wrong, tell me which part.

Comment: Thank you very much! I apologize for being not clear about my problem. Nevertheless you understood it and answered perfectly!